# Sorting a list depending on every other element in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, structure, python-3.4

If I have a list with elements which follows the structure:

```
[team1, points1, playedgames1, team2, points2, playedgames2, team3, points3, playedgames3]
```

and so on. An example (with 3 teams):

```
ls = ["Milan", 6, 2, "Inter", 3, 2, "Juventus", 5, 2]
```

and would like it to look like this:

```
["Inter", 3, 2, "Juventus", 5, 2, "Milan", 6, 2]
```

and so on for more teams. As you can see, the list is now sorted after the lowest point first. Essentially, it now is:

```
["team2, points2, playedgames2, team3, points3, playedgames3, team1, points2, playedgames2]
```

due to the fact that points2 had the lowest value. So, can I sort the list like this, with respect to the points but also to keep the structure of the list with (team, points, played games) and so on. Is this possible?

The elements are retrieved from a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
ls = ["Milan", 6, 2, "Inter", 3, 2, "Juventus", 5, 2]
>>> sorted([ls[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(ls),3)], key=lambda x:x[1])
[['Inter', 3, 2], ['Juventus', 5, 2], ['Milan', 6, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, and it is understandable too!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to convert records from file to list of tuples.
After it you can solve you problem by simple:

```
ls.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Or you can create function:

```
def my_sort(my_list):
   list_of_tuples = sorted([tuple(l[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3], key=operator.itemgetter(0))
   arr = []
   for i in b:
       arr += [i[0]] + [i[1]]
   return arr
```

Also, `operator.itemgetter` works faster.

> In [17]: %%timeit
>   sorted(a, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
>
> 10000 loops, best of 3: 114 µs per loop
>
> In [18]: %%timeit
>   sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
>
> 10000 loops, best of 3: 210 µs per loop

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

L = (team1, points1, playedgames1, team2, points2, playedgames2, team3, points3, playedgames3)
L = [tuple(L[i:i+3]) for i in range(None, len(L), 3)]
answer = sorted(L, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

Comment: Would that also work if it was supposed to be a list (I accidentally wrote parenthesis instead of brackets, edited now)?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split your list with step 3 then compare based on sorted list of second value and sorted of that create the last list  :

```
>>> new=[ls[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(ls),3)]
>>> new
[('Milan', 6, 2), ('Inter', 3, 2), ('Juventus', 5, 2)]
>>> val2_l=sorted(zip(*new)[1])
>>> val2_l
[3, 5, 6]
>>> v=zip(*new)[1]
>>> v
(6, 3, 5)
>>> ["team{}, points{}, playedgames{}".format(v.index(i)+1,v.index(i)+1,v.index(i)+1) for i in val2_l]
['team2, points2, playedgames2', 'team3, points3, playedgames3', 'team1, points1, playedgames1']
>>> [''.join(last)]
['team2, points2, playedgames2team3, points3, playedgames3team1, points1, playedgames1']
```